# Merging 3 separately coloured shapes in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I'm having an issue with combining/merging 3 separately coloured shapes into one. My goal is to create one shape (The letter C) while keeping the separate colour segments. (None of the shapes overlap as you can see in the photo) I eventually want to use Illustrator CC's "Live Corner" function to round the edges of the entire outline of this multi-coloured shape. Is this possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Thanks so much,
Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

Different colors require different object. The only way to "combine" them at all is the Group them (`Object > Group`).

Comment: Thanks Scott, really appreciate the answer. 

I'll have to make the multi coloured shape manually.